# How to get a name or word from a string that is inside a JSON value in Android Studio?

Tags: json, rest, android-studio, kotlin, data-class

I'm not sure If the title is correct, but I'll explain what I mean. So I'm doing a project that involves an API. I created the data classes that was need to store that information as well. Where it gets weird is actually getting the information I need. Here's an instance of a list of information I need for the project.

`"Text":"Alma Gutierrez - Alma M. Gutierrez is a fictional character on the HBO drama The Wire, played by actress Michelle Paress. Gutierrez is a dedicated and idealistic young reporter on the city desk of The Baltimore Sun."`

You see, the name of the character and the description is all in a single string value. I'm usually used to name and the description being separated like this for example

```
Text:{
      name: "Alma Gutierrez"
      description:"Alma is a..."
}
```

So my question is, how can I manipulate the response so that I can get the name and the description separately? I am thinking maybe some sort of function that will take the string value from the JSON call and split it to a name and description values. But I'm not sure how to do that.

I'll leave my project GitHub URL so you guys for reference. Thanks for the help.

https://github.com/OEThe11/AnywhereCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) to split a string into parts based on a delimiter.

For instance, if you have a string containing the description as mentioned in the question, you can do the following:

```kotlin
val text = "Alma Gutierrez - Alma M. Gutierrez is a fictional character on the HBO drama The Wire, played by actress Michelle Paress. Gutierrez is a dedicated and idealistic young reporter on the city desk of The Baltimore Sun."

val (name, description) = text.split(" - ", limit = 2)
```

(see the behaviour [in this playground](https://pl.kotl.in/rKIsEWOif))

The `limit = 2` parameter ensures that you won't miss a part of the description if it contains  `-` . It only splits in maximum 2 parts, so it will consider everything until the first occurrence of  `-`  as the name, and everything after that as the description, even if it includes more occurrences of  `-` .

Note that using the deconstruction `val (name, description) = ...` like this will fail if `split()` returns less than 2 parts (in other words, it will fail if the initial text doesn't contain  `-`  at all. It may be ok for you depending on the input you expect here.

Comment: OK, I understand that. But how would I call those values to the UI? would it be Text.name and text.description?

Comment: You would have to use the variables created in the second line

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what Joffery said, I actually created a variable to hold the the spited string.

```
 val parts = Text.split(" - ", limit = 2)
```

Since there's only two values in the split, I can use the variable and call the index that I need for the corresponding text field.

Comment: Why do you find accessing `parts[0]` and `parts[1]` better than using 2 individual `name` and `description` variables like in my answer?

Comment: It wasn't allowing me to set two variables at the same time for some reason.